# How to individually label points in Openlayers linestring?

Tags: labeling, openlayers, linestring

I want to display some text below each point on a linestring with Openlayers.  The text would include, for example, the coordinates of the point, plus some other information.

I have managed to add a style to these points, but so far only the same style to all.

https://jsfiddle.net/wainwrightalex/6qbpqmme/8/

I considered creating a new feature for each point, but I would like to avoid this if possible, so I can still use ol.interaction.Modify to edit the linestring.

Is it possible to somehow style these points individually?  Or add individual text in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the geometry config option of ol.style.Style and use a function to create a point at every vertex (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.style.html#GeometryFunction)

See also this blog post for some related information: http://boundlessgeo.com/2015/04/geometry-based-styling-openlayers-3/

Comment: Thanks. For completeness, here is a working solution with different labels on each point: https://jsfiddle.net/wainwrightalex/6qbpqmme/